# C# Regex for masking E-Mails

Tags: c#, regex, email

Is there a simple way for masking E-Mail addresses using Regular Expressions in `C#`?

**My E-Mail**:

```
myawesomeuser@there.com
```

**My goal**:

```
**awesome****@there.com (when 'awesome' was part of the pattern)
```

So it's more like an inverted replacement where evertyhing that does not actually match will be replaced with `*`.

**Note**: The domain should never be replaced!

From a performance side of view, would it make more sense to split by the `@` and only check the first part then put it back together afterwards?

**Note**: I don't want to check if the E-Mail is valid or not. It's just a simple inverted replacement and only for my current needs, the string is an E-Mail but for sure it can be any other string as well.

**Solution**

After reading the comments I ended up with an extension-method for strings which perfectly matches my needs.

```
public static string MaskEmail(this string eMail, string pattern)
{
    var ix1 = eMail.IndexOf(pattern, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var ix2 = eMail.IndexOf('@');

    // Corner case no-@
    if (ix2 == -1)
    {
        ix2 = eMail.Length;
    }

    string result;

    if (ix1 != -1 && ix1 < ix2)
    {
        result = new string('*', ix1) + pattern + new string('*', ix2 - ix1 - pattern.Length) + eMail.Substring(ix2);
    }
    else
    {
        // corner case no str found, all the pre-@ is replaced
        result = new string('*', ix2) + eMail.Substring(ix2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

which then can be called

```
string eMail = myawesomeuser@there.com;

string maskedMail = eMail.MaskEmail("awesome"); // **awesome****@there.com
```

Comment: So you want to * the first 2 and the last 4 characters? so abcdef@none.com would become ******@none.com?

Comment: @xanatos: No. The matching part can change. When searching for awesome, **awesome****@there.com should be the result and searching for user should result in *********user@there.com.

Comment: @KingKerosin I read the question one more time and understood that, Therefore i removed my old comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string email = "myawesomeuser@there.com";
string str = "awesome";

string rx = "^((?!" + Regex.Escape(str) + "|@).)*|(?<!@.*)(?<=" + Regex.Escape(str) + ")((?!@).)*";

string email2 = Regex.Replace(email, rx, x => {
    return new string('*', x.Length);
});
```

There are two sub-regular expressions here:

```
^((?!" + Regex.Escape(str) + "|@).)*
```

and

```
(?<!@.*)(?<=" + Regex.Escape(str) + ")((?!@).)*
```

They are in `|` (or)

The first one means: from the start of the string, any character but stop when you find `str` (escaped) or `@`

The second one means: there mustn't be a `@` before the start of this matching and, starting from `str` (escaped), replace any character stopping at the `@`

Probably faster/easier to read:

```
string email = "myawesomeuser@there.com";
string str = "awesome";

int ix1 = email.IndexOf(str);
int ix2 = email.IndexOf('@');

// Corner case no-@
if (ix2 == -1) {
    ix2 = email.Length;
}

string email3;

if (ix1 != -1 && ix1 < ix2) {
    email3 = new string('*', ix1) + str + new string('*', ix2 - ix1 - str.Length) + email.Substring(ix2);
} else {
    // corner case no str found, all the pre-@ is replaced
    email3 = new string('*', ix2) + email.Substring(ix2);
}
```

This second version is better because it handle corner cases like: string not found and no domain in the email.

Answer (score 0):

```
(awesome)|.(?=.*@)
```

Try this.Replace by `*$1`.But there will be an extra `*` at the start.So remove a `*` from the masked email from the start.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/29

Answer (score 0):

Non RE;

```
string name = "awesome";
int pat     = email.IndexOf('@');
int pname   = email.IndexOf(name);

if (pname < pat)
    email = new String('*', pat - name.Length).Insert(pname, name) + email.Substring(pat);
```